# The Probability the number of flips of a fair coin to achieve $3$ heads is $\mod 3$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, expected-value

> Compute the probability that the number of flips of a fair coin needed in order to achieve a total of exactly $3$ Heads will be a multiple of $3.$

This problem is from the 2021 FARML, which is a mock American Regions Math League tournament. I am having some trouble with this problem. I was given a hint to calculate the probability that the number of flips needed to get **one** head was congruent to $0, 1, 2 \pmod{3}.$ However, I'm not completely sure how to do this either, though I think it has something to do with probability with states or geometric series. Furthermore, even if we know the probability that the number of flips needed to get one head $\equiv 0, 1,2 \pmod{3},$ I'm not sure what to do after that. May I have some help? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Actually, I think I realize how to calculate one head congruent to $0, 1, 2 \pmod{3}.$ You get a geometric series for each of the three possible flips $0, 1, 2 \pmod{3}.$ However, I'm still not sure how to continue.

Comment: Find the probability for $x=3k$ for some arbitrary $k\ge 0$. Sum to infinity.

Comment: Yep, got the one head part. For the probability congruent to $0 \pmod{3},$ we will get $\tfrac{1}{8} + \tfrac{1}{64} + \tfrac{1}{512} + \cdots = \tfrac{1}{7}.$

Comment: That's nothing like  what I get.  I agree that the probability that it takes $3$ tosses is $\frac18$, but the probability that it takes $6$ tosses is $$\binom522^{-6}=\frac{5}{32}$$ so that the probability that it takes either $3$ or $6$ tosses is greater than $\frac9{32} >\frac17$

Comment: The probability of getting $3$ tosses of which on the third one is a head is $\tfrac{1}{8}.$ The probability of getting $6$ tosses of which the final is a head is $\tfrac{1}{2^6} = \tfrac{1}{64}.$ This goes on forming a geometric series.

Comment: Per the comment of @saulspatz , let $f(k)$ denote the probability that it takes exactly $(3k)$ coin flips to get $(3)$ heads.  For clarification, this means that you got **exactly** $(2)$ heads on the first $(3k-1)$ coin flips and then got a heads on the $(3k)$-th coin flip.  **Then**, you want $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k).$$

Comment: Wait.  I finally understand what you mean.  $\frac17$ is the probability that the first head takes $0\pmod3$ tosses.  That's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping flipping a coin until a head is achieved. We have ...

The probability that exactly $1$ heads will be achieved in $ 1 \pmod 3 $ flips is $ \frac{4}{7}$.

The probability that exactly $1$ heads will be achieved in $ 2 \pmod 3 $ flips is $ \frac{2}{7}$.

The probability that exactly $1$ heads will be achieved in $ 0 \pmod 3 $ flips is $ \frac{1}{7}$.

Now consider achieveing $3$ heads, the first after $a$ flips, the second after a further $b$ flips & the third after a further $c$ flips. We require $a+b+c \equiv 0 \pmod 3 $. And $a,b,c$ can be chosen in the following ways...

Now $1+1+1$ (In one way) or $2+2+2$ (In one way) or $0+0+0$ (In one way) or $0+1+2$ (in $6$ ways) so ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
p= \left( \frac{4}{7} \right)^3+\left( \frac{2}{7} \right)^3+\left( \frac{1}{7} \right)^3+ 6 \times \frac{1}{7} \frac{2}{7} \frac{4}{7}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: May I point out $0+0+0$ and $2+2+2?$ I think we also add those, since both $0$ and $6$ are $0 \pmod{3},$ otherwise I think this is correct. Thanks very much :) Edit: I'm a little confused on why we have to cube it...

Comment: @StarLight You are right ... (brain freeze !) ... I have corrected it now.

Comment: Nevermind the question about cubing. I understand it now. Thanks very much. By the way, out of curiosity, is there a way to find the probability of 1 heads $ \equiv 0, 1, 2 \pmod{3}$ without using a geometric series? Possibly with expected probability?